# First element offset

Tags: c, malloc, free, offset

Is it a WARRANTY, that offset of first element of structure is 0?
To be more accurate, lets consider

```
struct foo {
int a;
double b;
};
struct foo *ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
int *int_ptr = &ptr->a;
free(int_ptr)
```

Is it garantied, that it is valid always, under any os or any other factors?

Comment: Under *any* OS or *any* other factors?  I don't know if that can be answered -- whether it is in the language specification is a different story.

Comment: Shouldn't your code read `int *int_ptr = &ptr->a;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is guaranteed. Will get you a standard quote, let me lookup.

**C99 Standard: §6.7.2.1**

**Para 12**

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-ﬁeld members and the units in which bit-ﬁelds
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.**

Comment: §6.7.2.15 seems about right: "*A pointer to a
structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. **There may be unnamed
padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning**.*"

Comment: @DCoder: Ah, You beat me to that :)